# My ViewController is getting really big due to UI coding

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I am working on a project which got all the task done in a singe **viewController**. As there are so many elements on the **viewController** I choose to do the **UI** with coding, like this:

```
  let myButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openFunction), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()
```

As there are so many **button**, **view**, **texifield**, **label** etc along with all their **constraints** written with code, my **viewController** class getting bigger and bigger. How can I keep all the **UI** code in separate file and integrate in on my **viewController** ? I don't know there might be really easy way to do that but I am actually struggling. Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A specific answer to your specific code would be to create a `convenience` initializer in an extension to `UIButton`.

```
extension UIButton {
    convenience init(_ target:Any, _ action:Selector) {
        self.init(CGRect.zero)
        self.addTarget(target, action:action)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

Right there you are probably cutting back on things in your VC.

Next, consider moving this - and all - UI code out of your VC file and into other files. I typically move my extensions/subclasses into as many files as needed. (The build *may* take longer but the final binary should be the same size.) For large projects, this helps make things manageable.

At the same time consider making an extension to your VC *specifically* for auto layout (which I see you are using because you are setting your `UIButton` auto resizing mask). As long as you are declaring your objects in the main subclassed VC, this removes the "verbose" nature of auto layout into it's own file.

For multi-developer projects and/or true "reusable" code, a final thing you can do is move code into a Framework target.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of design patterns and code architecture. They are various ways to accomplish what you are after. It's a good sign you are able to identify this problem early.

You can start looks at *MVVM, VIPER, ReSwift* among others. Research which fits your the requirements of your app.

**Suggestions for Reducing UI Code in view controller:**

In terms of reducing just the UI Code growing in the view controller, I suggest start creating subclasses of common elements and keey your code DRY. For instance, if a UIButton with same fonts and borders etc are being created many times then look at creating a subclass for it and move the configurations inside this subclass.

You can also create subview of logical elements on the screen, example you have a header with buttons and labels then move it into a subclass and start using this subclass from here on. This should improve your code readability and reuse.

You can also reduce a lot of the autlayout code by [create extensions](https://github.com/roberthein/TinyConstraints) of commons layouts like pinning to all corners etc this way the repetition of boilerplate auto layout code is much less.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @carbonr, I was also thinking I might have to use **subclass** & **extension** a lot here. Eventually I guess thats the way to do it. I also follow design pattern for api handling but never user design pattern for **UI**, your suggestion is a gem.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to what carbonr has proposed is to leverage Interface Builder.  With Interface Builder, you can create one or more StoryBoards and separate UI elements and constraints from the controller that contains your code.  Obviously, if you are unfamiliar with Interface Builder there would be a learning curve.

Comment: Thats a nice suggestion as well @martin, but I am currently switching from Interface Builder. It tweaks so frequently, when there is a new Xcode version it tweaks, if I copy and paste it on other mac it tweaks. Had these kind of issue before, therefore I am switching to code now a days. Its time consuming to write the code but once it done its really stable to my point of view.

Comment: I understand.  I've had my share of issues with Interface Builder as well.  Good luck!